macOS Sonoma's Compress contextual menu, how can I add numbering to Zip results?
macOS provides "Compress" in the Finder's contextual menu. I use it a lot to create a quick archive of a file before I edit and test the new results.  I keep several archives of a file around until I am sure I can delete them.
But the first time I compress a file it has no number added to it. Then the second time the number 2 gets added. But this means the files do not sort properly in the Finder.
I know this is not a huge issue, but is there some command line action to force the Archive utility to add "1" the first time I compress a file?
